# Merging and Concating using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

Hi I have 2 dataframes as below:

| key | Apple | Banana |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 1 | 12 |
| bcd | 23 | 21 |

| key | Train | Car |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 11 | 20 |
| jkn | 2 | 19 |

I want to merge these 2 dataframes together with my key column so that I can get following table:

| key | Train | Car | Banana | Apple |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 11 | 20 | 12 | 1 |
| jkn | 2 | 19 | 0/NA | 0/NA |
| bcd | 0/NA | 0/NA | 21 | 23 |

For columns where I don't have any record like for `jkn / Apple` either 0 or NA should be printed.

Currently I tried using `pd.concat` but am not exactly able to figure out how to get my desired result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `pd.merge()` with `how='outer'`, [read further in documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/merging.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data_string = """key    Apple   Banana
abc 1   12
bcd 23  21
"""

df1 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data_string), sep='\s+')

data_string = """key    Train   Car
abc 11  20
jkn 2   19"""
df2 = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data_string), sep='\s+')

# Solution
df_result = pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['key'], how='outer')
```

```
print(df_result)
   key  Apple  Banana  Train   Car
0  abc    1.0    12.0   11.0  20.0
1  bcd   23.0    21.0    NaN   NaN
2  jkn    NaN     NaN    2.0  19.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's try `concat` then `groupby.sum`

```py
out = (pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index=True)
       .groupby('key', as_index=False).sum())
```

```
print(out)

   key  Apple  Banana  Train   Car
0  abc    1.0    12.0   11.0  20.0
1  bcd   23.0    21.0    0.0   0.0
2  jkn    0.0     0.0    2.0  19.0
```